# Pagination is not working with custom query inside a homepage template

Tags: wp-query, pagination

There are a lot of similar questions asked here, but none of the suggestions seems to work for me.

I have the following code on my home page:

```
get_template_part( 'category-clients' );
```

And category-clients.php looks like this:

```
        <div id="content">
        <?php
          global $paged;
          global $wp_query;
          $temp = $wp_query; 
          $wp_query = null; 
          $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
          $wp_query->query('cat=251&posts_per_page=3'.'&paged='.$paged);
          while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div id="pagination">
        <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
        </div>

        <?php 
          $wp_query = null; 
          $wp_query = $temp; 
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Also... below this code, on category-clients.php, I have a jQuery script for AJAX loading of the different pages:

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// AJAX pagination
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('#content').on('click', '#pagination a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#content').fadeOut(500, function(){
            jQuery(this).load(link + ' #content', function() {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Now... if I go to $myurl/clients, the pagination works just fine, but on the homepage it doesn't. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it work. Leaving the answer here in case someone else have the same problem.

```
        <div id="content">

        <?php
            global $paged;
            global $new_query;
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
            query_posts( array( 'cat' => 251, 'paged' => $paged ) );
            $new_query = new WP_Query();
            $new_query->query('cat=251&posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged);
        ?>

        <?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div id="pagination">
        <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $new_query->max_num_pages) ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
        </div>

    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Comment: it's probably helpful to explain *why* this solved it. On page post type the page number is in the `page` global rather than `paged`, which is for archive pagination.

Comment: This answer also helped me.